# How do I overcome this error?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to deploy my .NET Framework app via Visual Studio to Google Compute Engine and I keep getting the error below.

---

Steps taken to remedy the error

---

My Web Management is started, Web deploy is installed and the Extral Ip address of my cloud instance is added to web.conf file as new connection string. Has any encountered same issue before and if so hw did you solve it.

Thanks.

```
Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer 
("35.196.125.112"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is 
installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  
Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?
LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)
```

---

First Issue SOLVED, New Issue below

---

[image]

I'm trying to deploy my .NET Framework app from Visual Studio to Google Compute Engine on windows 7 using IIS7. I'm using CustomProfile to deploy to my app and my app makes use of a database. I didn't modify the of web.config file (my suspect for the issue), I tried adding the external IP as my data source but no luck and therefore left i was using it to migrate and update my local db. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

---

Web Config

---

```
<add name="ClassifiedDB" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;user 
id=UID;password=PWD initial catalog=ClassifiedDB;integrated security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I didnt set google anything on the Web config file.

Comment: Where is your Data Base running? And maybe create a new thread for the new issue since they are not related.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the WEB MANAGEMENT SERVICES to "auto" and restart.
Hope the following link helps.[Microsoft Configure Web Deployment Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler)

Comment: Thanks I was able to figure by using cloud launcher which basically creates instances for me rather than manually do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your firewall rules? You can do this [here](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) (be sure to select the correct project on the center-left top hand side). Take a look at [Installing and Configuring Web Deploy...Troubleshooting section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later#troubleshooting-common-issues) for the ports you need to open.

Also, if you could give more info on how you set up your instance, is it a custom instance or did you use [Google Cloud ASP.NET Framework Launcher](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/aspnet)? If it is custom, what Windows, IIS, versions do you have, what .NET Framework are you targeting?
And, can you confirm that you are not using [Google Cloud Visual Studio Extension](https://cloud.google.com/visual-studio/) but trying to deploy to Google Cloud using Web Deploy directly?

Comment: I have solved the initial issue and I'm able to establish a connection btw my app and the server. However, I've encountered a new problem, basically a Runtime error but I', assuming that it has to do with my connection string/web config file because i'm not sure if I have configured it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the new Issue.
It's really hard to know what's actually going wrong in the application.  I would not set `customErrors="on"` because it would risk exposing a secret like an SQL connection string.

A tool that can catch and privately report the error is [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/).
[This sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/vs2015/error-reporting/api/diagnostics/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs) shows you how to use Stackdriver with an ASP.NET 4.x application.

Comment: thanks for the response. I think the site is deployed successfully but I cant seem to deploy my database with it. I have created and Instance and all that but I cant seem to figure out how  to get it to work. Basically, I think the issue is web.conf file and I think I diidnt set it  correctly...........